# Detect if current file has specific word

Tags: vim

In Vim, I'm trying to detect if my current PHP file has a constructor, i.e. if the following exists:

```
public function __construct()
{
    //
}
```

In VimScript, I can easily move to the constructor by doing:

```
exec 'normal gg/construct'
```

However I'd like to detect, if the constructor is present or not and run a different command.

Comment: When do you wanna do it? When you open the file?

Comment: You don't need `:execute`, here: `normal gg/construct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `search()` then. It'll return the first matching line number.